# no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.run/3

Tags: elixir, ecto

Following this tutorial https://curiosum.dev/blog/elixir-ecto-database-transactions

```
  alias Ecto.Multi
  alias ElixirRest.Account
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

  require Logger

  def transfer_money(acc1_id, acc2_id, amount) do
    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.run(:retrieve_accounts_step, retrieve_accounts(acc1_id, acc2_id))
    |> Multi.run(:verify_balances_step, verify_balances(amount))
    |> Multi.run(:subtract_from_a_step, &subtract_from_a/2)
    |> Multi.run(:add_to_b_step, &add_to_b/2)
  end

  defp retrieve_accounts(acc1_id, acc2_id) do
    fn repo, _ ->
      case from(acc in Account, where: acc.id in [^acc1_id, ^acc2_id]) |> repo.all() do
        [acc_a, acc_b] -> {:ok, {acc_a, acc_b}}
        _ -> {:error, :account_not_found}
      end
    end
  end

  defp verify_balances(transfer_amount) do
    fn _repo, %{retrieve_accounts_step: {acc_a, acc_b}} ->
      if acc_a.balance < transfer_amount,
         do: {:error, :balance_too_low},
         else: {:ok, {acc_a, acc_b, transfer_amount}}
    end
  end

  defp subtract_from_a(repo, %{verify_balances_step: {acc_a, _, verified_amount}}) do
    acc_a
    |> Account.changeset(%{balance: acc_a.balance - verified_amount})
    |> repo.update()
  end

  defp add_to_b(repo, %{verify_balances_step: {_, acc_b, verified_amount}}) do
    acc_b
    |> Account.changeset(%{balance: acc_b.balance + verified_amount})
    |> repo.update()
  end
end
```

Calling like this:
`ElixirRest.Account.Batches.transfer_money(input.from_account, input.to_account, input.sum) |> ElixirRest.Repo.transaction()`

Error message:

```
[error] #PID<0.459.0> running ElixirRestWeb.Endpoint (cowboy_protocol) terminated
Server: localhost:8081 (http)
Request: POST /api/graphiql
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Multi.run/3
        (ecto 2.2.12) lib/ecto/multi.ex:309: Ecto.Multi.run(%Ecto.Multi{names: #MapSet<[]>, operations: []}, :retrieve_accounts_step, #Function<0.17156638/2 in ElixirRest.Account.Batches.retrieve_accounts/2>)
        (elixir_rest 0.0.1) lib/elixir_rest_web/resolvers/transaction_resolver.ex:17: ElixirRestWeb.Resolvers.TransactionResolver.create_transaction/3
        (absinthe 1.4.16) lib/absinthe/resolution.ex:209: Absinthe.Resolution.call/2
        (absinthe 1.4.16) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:209: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.reduce_resolution/1
        (absinthe 1.4.16) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:168: Absinthe.Phase.Document.Execution.Resolution.do_resolve_field/4
        (absinthe 1.4.16) lib/absinthe/phase/document/execution/resolution.ex:153:
```

What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?
What is causing this problem?

Code:writing ratio in questions is a stupid verification

Answer (score 0):

I was using an outdated version of ecto,(2.2)

I thought I was on 3 but I wasn't.